# How to Disable Nginx's module Nchan

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've had some problems with Nginx occasionally and i noticed it was some error of the module `Nchan` occasionaly crashing and preventing Nginx from accepting connections.

I don't use Nchan so i'd like to disable it, i've searched online how to do that and everything points to removing the link from `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled` but my installation doesn't have that folder (**Ubuntu 16**, `nginx-extras` installed via `apt-get`).

I've also looked in `nginx.conf` and there's nothing in there about that either.

Version installed:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
```

How can i disable it?

**EDIT**

Here's some extra info about the package:

```
$ apt-cache policy nginx-extras 
nginx-extras:
  Installed: 1:1.18.0-8.6.0.6~xenial1
  Candidate: 1:1.18.0-8.6.0.6~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.18.0-8.6.0.6~xenial1 500
        500 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Exactly whose package of nginx did you install? Which Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16 like stated in the post, i'll edit it with extra information about the installed version.

Comment: Do you mean that it's 16.04 LTS? Just "16" is too vague and doesn't actually specify any particular distro version.

Comment: ah yes sorry, 16.04 LTS

Comment: Hm. That looks like a third party build of nginx, which is probably why you find everything online doesn't apply to you. You should consider switching back to distro nginx or nginx PPA which has nchan separated out into a separate package, and dumping Phusion Passenger.

Comment: why would i dump passenger? that's what i'm using to run all my Rails apps

Comment: There are other ways to run Rails apps. Some of them are significantly better than Passenger, at least if you aren't paying for the enterprise version (which it seems you aren't). Here's [one comparison](https://scoutapm.com/blog/which-ruby-app-server-is-right-for-you); it's possible to find others and with similar results.

Comment: thanks i'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

> On Debian derivatives the directory /etc/nginx/modules-enabled
> contains the configuration files used to load modules (or better
> symbolic links to the configuration files). You just need to delete
> the appropriate file and reload nginx:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

Try this command to disabled nginx:

```
/******* if you disabled nginx try this command ********/   

sudo update-rc.d -f nginx disable
```

Comment: did you actually read the question?

Comment: He is correct. At least for Ubuntu 18.04. Read his quote. To disable nchan: `cd /etc/nginx/ && sudo mv modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf modules-available/50-mod-nchan.conf` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx`. If you wanna search the file `mod-nchan.conf` system-wide you can do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install mlocate` and `sudo updatedb && sudo locate mod-nchan.conf`.